# Java jackson cannot deserialise array of objects in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a problem with Java Jackson when I try to deserialise.

```
public class Mapper {

public static Map<String, Object> JsonToMap(String json)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    // Convert the JSON recieved through POST request to a HasMap
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });
    return map;

}
```

Here is the JSON

```
{[
"UserMealDay": {
    "date": "2016-04-04",
    "slot_num": "1"
},
"Recipe": {
    "id": "82",
    "name": "Porridge with Banana & Sunflower Seeds",
    "RecipeIngredient": [{
        "id": "110263",
        "multiplier": null,
        "quantity": "50.00",
        "ingredient_id": "486",
        "ingredient_unit_id": "8",
        "recipe_id": "82",
        "Ingredient": {
            "id": "486",
            "name": "jumbo oats",
            "plural": "jumbo oats",
            "IngredientGroup": [{
                "id": "19",
                "name": "Oats",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "160",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "19",
                    "ingredient_id": "486",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }]
        },
        "IngredientUnit": {
            "id": "8",
            "short": "g",
            "name": "g",
            "plural": "g",
            "created": "2015-07-14 20:10:33",
            "modified": "2015-07-24 09:25:22",
            "deleted": "0",
            "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "110264",
        "multiplier": null,
        "quantity": "100.00",
        "ingredient_id": "182",
        "ingredient_unit_id": "18",
        "recipe_id": "82",
        "Ingredient": {
            "id": "182",
            "name": "cold water",
            "plural": "cold water",
            "IngredientGroup": [{
                "id": "59",
                "name": "Misc",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "465",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "59",
                    "ingredient_id": "182",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }, {
                "id": "121",
                "name": "water",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "1104",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "121",
                    "ingredient_id": "182",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }]
        },
        "IngredientUnit": {
            "id": "18",
            "short": "ml",
            "name": "ml",
            "plural": "ml",
            "created": "2015-07-14 20:11:43",
            "modified": "2015-07-24 09:42:29",
            "deleted": "0",
            "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "110265",
        "multiplier": null,
        "quantity": "100.00",
        "ingredient_id": "815",
        "ingredient_unit_id": "18",
        "recipe_id": "82",
        "Ingredient": {
            "id": "815",
            "name": "milk",
            "plural": "milk",
            "IngredientGroup": [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Dairy",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "1158",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "1",
                    "ingredient_id": "815",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Cows Milk",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "1159",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "3",
                    "ingredient_id": "815",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }]
        },
        "IngredientUnit": {
            "id": "18",
            "short": "ml",
            "name": "ml",
            "plural": "ml",
            "created": "2015-07-14 20:11:43",
            "modified": "2015-07-24 09:42:29",
            "deleted": "0",
            "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "110266",
        "multiplier": null,
        "quantity": "1.00",
        "ingredient_id": "707",
        "ingredient_unit_id": "23",
        "recipe_id": "82",
        "Ingredient": {
            "id": "707",
            "name": "banana",
            "plural": "bananas ",
            "IngredientGroup": [{
                "id": "45",
                "name": "Tropical fruit",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "340",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "45",
                    "ingredient_id": "707",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }]
        },
        "IngredientUnit": {
            "id": "23",
            "short": "qty",
            "name": "qty",
            "plural": "qty",
            "created": "2015-07-14 20:12:19",
            "modified": "2015-07-24 09:43:13",
            "deleted": "0",
            "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "110267",
        "multiplier": null,
        "quantity": "20.00",
        "ingredient_id": "280",
        "ingredient_unit_id": "8",
        "recipe_id": "82",
        "Ingredient": {
            "id": "280",
            "name": "sunflower seeds",
            "plural": "sunflower seeds",
            "IngredientGroup": [{
                "id": "79",
                "name": "Seeds",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "584",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "79",
                    "ingredient_id": "280",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }]
        },
        "IngredientUnit": {
            "id": "8",
            "short": "g",
            "name": "g",
            "plural": "g",
            "created": "2015-07-14 20:10:33",
            "modified": "2015-07-24 09:25:22",
            "deleted": "0",
            "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "110268",
        "multiplier": null,
        "quantity": "1.00",
        "ingredient_id": "493",
        "ingredient_unit_id": "31",
        "recipe_id": "82",
        "Ingredient": {
            "id": "493",
            "name": "honey",
            "plural": "honey",
            "IngredientGroup": [{
                "id": "87",
                "name": "Non-refined\/ Natural sugar",
                "IngredientGroupsIngredient": {
                    "id": "630",
                    "ingredient_group_id": "87",
                    "ingredient_id": "493",
                    "created": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "deleted": "0",
                    "deleted_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                }
            }, .......
```

The TypeReferencing can only use only primitive variables, and I must use String[] as my first parameter instead of String.
What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: How does a `String[]` map to an object? Can you show an example of your json String?

Comment: I have edited the post, it's in the description now :) thanx!

Comment: It's an array of objects.

Comment: Have you tried using `TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>` ? Using a `Map<String[], Object>` (which _is_ possible), seems like a very strange choice to me.

Comment: It doesn't work, I get syntax errors on it

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing it now myself. It seems like your json is malformed. iirc, only the root object can be anonymous. But you also have anonymous array inside your root object. It works for me with `TypeReference<List<‌​Map<String, Object>>>` if I switch the `{` and `[` at the beginning and end.

Comment: I did what you have said, but I get java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map] when I try to make TypeReference<List<‌​Map<String, Object>>>

Comment: You should also assign it to a variable of that type i.e.: `List<‌‌​​Map<String, Object>> list = mapper.readValue(...);`

Comment: I think that won't return you a map, but a List<object> instead.